# Insert String into JDBC SQLite database

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I am creating a java application that requires a local database. I am using a SQLite database with JDBC. I am new to Java local database and JDBC.

From tutorials on the internet I have just about worked out what I am doing, but it is not very clear to me. I am now trying to create a method that can take in a table name and a set of strings and add them to the table.

I am having 2 problems:

First, the method does not accept table as a parameter to pass in. I know I can create a method for each table, but this is inefficient and if possible I would like one method to work for all tables.

Second, I cannot work out how to pass the strings into the table, because the data to be sent to the table is inside a SQL statement and does not recognise the Java string.

Below is the method so far:

```
public static void Insert(Table table, String id, String name, String age, String address, String salary) {
    Connection c = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
        c.setAutoCommit(false);
        System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

        stmt = c.createStatement();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY) "
                + "VALUES (1, 'Paul', 32, 'California', 20000.00 );";
        //I want this to write the strings passed in by the method, and to the table passed in by the method
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        stmt.close();
        c.commit();
        c.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
    System.out.println("Records created successfully");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Prepared Statement instead of CreateStatement as follows:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = c.prepareStatement
      ("insert into COMPANY values(?,?,?,?,?)");
      stmt.setInt(1,1);
      stmt.setString(2,"Paul");
      stmt.setInt(3,32);
      stmt.setString(4, "California");
      stmt.setBigDecimal(5, 20000.00);
      stmt.executeUpdate();
```

You should create a Prepared Statement for each Table that you want to insert into.
Alternatively you can build up the insert string dynamically with Table as a parameter

```
String insert_string = "insert into" + Table + "values, etc, etc"
```

Comment: what do the (?,?,?) represent? I have tried ("insert into COMPANY values(ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY)"); but it is giving me an error

Comment: The ? are placeholders. When you do setInt afterwards it will set the value to  corresponding setXX

Comment: The above code will insert data into the columns of the database in the default order that the database was created in. It is not necessary to specify the column names unless they are different from the default

Comment: how do I pass the table name in as Eclipse is not accepting Table as a parameter and String gives me a nullPointerException

Comment: `String myTableName` as a parameter to your Insert method

Comment: And you need to pass in a valid table name when you invoke your `Insert` method , eg `Insert ("COMPANY", id, other parameters....)`