# Import CSV into SQLite in Java

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, csv

I'm starting learning Java and need some help. I need to import CSV file into SQLite database. I have this CSV reader, but i don't know how to copy this data into SQLite database.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class csv {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        String csvFile = "/home/user/user.csv";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";

        try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] table = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
                  }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845643/insert-string-into-jdbc-sqlite-database): How to open a connection to SQLite db and insert records.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JDBC and prepared statements (check this documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/sql/PreparedStatement.html )

1. Download some JDBC driver for SQLite. For example, here https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc
2. Add JDBC jar to your classpath.
3. Write something like that:

   ```
   String dbName = "insert your db name here";
   Connection conn = null;
   try {
       // use your dbname instead
       conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:dbname");
       // use your tablename instead; set as much question marks as many fields you have
       PreparedStatement stmt =
           conn.prepareStatement("insert into tablename (column1, column2, column3) values (?, ?, ?)");
       br = ...;
       while (line = ...) {
           String[] table = ...;
           // set values to replace question marks in prepared statement
           stmt.setInt(1, table[0]);
           stmt.setString(2, table[1]);
           stmt.setString(3, table[2]);
           // so, know your statement is like insert into ... values (table[0], table[1], table[2])
           // and maybe add other fields...
           stmt.executeUpdate(); // insert data into table
       }
   } catch (...) { ...
   } finally { ...close conn and br... }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

if your loop stays like this you have to iterate through the array each line and pick the values and write them to your database. to write data to a sqlite database you should use google. you will find plenty examples on how to do that

Comment: ok, but i don't know how to combine this 2 things. can i pick the values and write them to my database in this loop?

Comment: `for(String str : table){//getSession().createQuery("INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME VALUES ("+str+")").executeUpdate()}`

Comment: something like that will do it